# Join two arrays in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

An aggregation yielded two arrays: `$array1` and `$array2`:

```
    $array1 = [{ key1_1: 0,
                 key1_2: 1,
                 key1_3: 2 
               },
               { key1_1: 0,
                 key1_2: 1,
                 key1_3: 2 
               }]

    $array2 = [{ key2_1: 0,
                 key2_2: 1 
               }, 
               { key2_1: 0,
                 key2_2: 1 
               }]
```

I would like to join them completely.

If I do this:

```
{ $project: { 'output': { $concatArrays: [ '$array1', '$array2' ] } }
```

the result will be this:

```
output: [{  key1_1: 0,
            key1_2: 1,
            key1_3: 2
          },
          { key2_1: 0,
            key2_2: 1 
          },
          { key1_1: 0,
            key1_2: 1,
            key1_3: 2
          },
          { key2_1: 0,
            key2_2: 1
          }]
```

whereas I would prefer this:

```
output: [{  key1_1: 0, 
            key1_2: 1,
            key1_3: 2,
            key2_1: 0,
            key2_2: 1
          },
          { key1_1: 0,
            key1_2: 1,
            key1_3: 2,
            key2_1: 0,
            key2_2: 1
          }]
```

I guess this is only possible by `$project`, but how?

Comment: There is no problem with joining arrays. But you are trying to join objects - copy fields from all objects into one object

Comment: Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: I notice the keys that are being used are repeated. Could you please specify a proper sample document? And it would be helpful, if you could provide details such as the number of fields in an array object, the number of objects in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, which is not exactly what I wanted, but it's good enough.

In the aggregation, first

```
{ $unwind: '$array1' },
{ $unwind: '$array2' },
```

then do a grouping:

```
{ $group: { _id: '$_id',
           arrays: { $push: { 
                              array1: '$array1',
                              array2: '$array2' 
                            }
                   }
           }
 },
```

The result will be:

```
"arrays": {[
             "array1": {
               ...
             },
             "array2": {
               ...
             }
           ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not aggregation could be easier?:

```
> var a =[];
> var array1 = [{ key1_1: 0,                  key1_2: 1,                  key1_3: 2                 },                { key1_1: 0,                  key1_2: 1,                  key1_3: 2                 }];
> var array2 = [{ key2_1: 0,                  key2_2: 1                 },                 { key2_1: 0,                  key2_2: 1                 }];
> array1.forEach(function(o,i){a.push(Object.assign(array1[i],array2[i]));});
> printjson(a);
[
        {
                "key1_1" : 0,
                "key1_2" : 1,
                "key1_3" : 2,
                "key2_1" : 0,
                "key2_2" : 1
        },
        {
                "key1_1" : 0,
                "key1_2" : 1,
                "key1_3" : 2,
                "key2_1" : 0,
                "key2_2" : 1
        }
]
```

Comment: Yes, it would be, but it's not a MongoDB solution. But obviously there is nothing better, so I'll settle with it.